# getting wrong data type from retrofit response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I got `userId` as `double` from retrofit2 response, but at response from the server side end it is a `string`

**retrofit response**

```
{
    "UserId": 1.0,
    "UserName": "suresh",
    "SiteCode": 0.0,
    "FullName": "suresh, suresh",
    "Employeecode": 0.0,
    "IsActive": 0.0,
    "ProfileURL": ""
}
```

**server response**

```
{
    "UserId": "1",
    "UserName": "suresh",
    "SiteCode": 0.0,
    "FullName": "suresh, suresh",
    "Employeecode": 0.0,
    "IsActive": 0.0,
    "ProfileURL": ""
}
```

Why am I getting like this, what is the reason and how to solve this

how to get the following as my response?

```
{
    "UserId": "1",
    "UserName": "suresh",
    "SiteCode": 0.0,
    "FullName": "suresh, suresh",
    "Employeecode": 0.0,
    "IsActive": 0.0,
    "ProfileURL": ""
}
```

this is my rest client

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        try {
            retrofit = null;
            if (retrofit == null) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

                         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        //.baseUrl("http://192.168.1.138/OMS_Orders/").client(client)
                        .baseUrl("someURL").client(client)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Exceptionerror", ex.toString());
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

and pojo class code is

```
public class LoginDTO {
 @SerializedName("SiteCode")
    private String SiteCode;

    @SerializedName("FullName")
    private String FullName;

    @SerializedName("Employeecode")
    private String Employeecode;

    @SerializedName("UserId")
    private String UserId;
}
```

Comment: post your response pojo class

Comment: that is json string, I'm getting from retrofit. I'm not using any class.

Comment: @PJain at server side it is string only, i ve checked it, but the response from the retrofit is wrong for some reason

Comment: what data type are you assigning for the UserId @PadmajaRani

Comment: @BrahmaDatta Im expecting string but it is not string. at server side it is string only,

Comment: can you post code where you are making retrofit network call

Comment: you need to convert your json to pojo. you can do that with gson. You can also parse your json string without any converters. There is nothing wrong with the retrofit.

Comment: here is answer https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Query.java.  maybe you don't have you used GsonConvertFactory when creating retrofit instance

Comment: If you are still unable to get that just try to remove the digits after "." by string manipulation methods. @PadmajaRani

Comment: @PJain yes.. im using GsonConvertFactory

Comment: Then add your code of pojo and instance you are making..

Comment: add POJO class code also

Comment: @Pjain pojo class is also added

Comment: Have you tried my method @PadmajaRani

Comment: cant i get userid from retrofit as userId:"1" ? my server response is like that only nah.. why would I use string manipulating methods like using split and taking first values from the string splitted

Comment: then you need to forcefully convert values where ever you want to use, means first parse double value then convert to int and at last convert to integer.

Comment: using string manipulations and converting value to double is not matters @PJain . I should know the reason why retrofit it self converting data type from string to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your POJO class for data is as below

```
public class DataList {

@SerializedName("UserId")
@Expose
private String userId;
@SerializedName("UserName")
@Expose
private String userName;
@SerializedName("SiteCode")
@Expose
private Double siteCode;
@SerializedName("FullName")
@Expose
private String fullName;
@SerializedName("Employeecode")
@Expose
private Double employeecode;
@SerializedName("IsActive")
@Expose
private Double isActive;
@SerializedName("ProfileURL")
@Expose
private String profileURL;

public String getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server is giving you the Response in such a way that the `userId` is a `string`. The values that are **String** are enclosed inside of double quotes ie. ("").

Now if you want to get `double` value for `userId` in your server response, you will have to change the backend code written in php or something else.

But you can easily make a POJO class for your Response like:

```
public class Response
{
    private String UserName;

    private String SiteCode;

    private String UserId;

    private String Employeecode;

    private String IsActive;

    private String FullName;

    private String ProfileURL;

    public String getUserName ()
    {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName (String UserName)
    {
        this.UserName = UserName;
    }

    public String getSiteCode ()
    {
        return SiteCode;
    }

    public void setSiteCode (String SiteCode)
    {
        this.SiteCode = SiteCode;
    }

    public String getUserId ()
    {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId (String UserId)
    {
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }

    public String getEmployeecode ()
    {
        return Employeecode;
    }

    public void setEmployeecode (String Employeecode)
    {
        this.Employeecode = Employeecode;
    }

    public String getIsActive ()
    {
        return IsActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive (String IsActive)
    {
        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }

    public String getFullName ()
    {
        return FullName;
    }

    public void setFullName (String FullName)
    {
        this.FullName = FullName;
    }

    public String getProfileURL ()
    {
        return ProfileURL;
    }

    public void setProfileURL (String ProfileURL)
    {
        this.ProfileURL = ProfileURL;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Response [UserName = "+UserName+", SiteCode = "+SiteCode+", UserId = "+UserId+", Employeecode = "+Employeecode+", IsActive = "+IsActive+", FullName = "+FullName+", ProfileURL = "+ProfileURL+"]";
    }
}
```

and whenever you need `userId` as double, you can do `double num = Double.parseDouble(StringValue);`

Comment: please understand the question first, at server side end im getting response as userId is string i.e as "1" and from retrofit response im getting userId as 1.0 and the key value pair showing it is a double value